# can't execute any hadoop command after installing cloudera manager

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I've set up my cdh cluster(5.14.0) successfully, which includes 4 nodes,and installed services including hdfs, yarn, zookeeper and impala. The cloudera manager web page works fine.

[image]

But when I open a terminal and try to run any hadoop command, like hadoop, impala or anything, the shell prompt "command not found".

I installed CM with user hadoop, and run all service in singer user mode with default user cloudera-scm. I know that CM should set enviroment variable for me, but seems it did not.

Really appreciate for any help!

Comment: Cloudera Manager doesn't modify your local `$PATH` variable

Answer (score 0):

Ensure CDH and other add on service parcels are downloaded and distributed to the hosts from cloudera manager server.

[image]

Add gateway roles to the host where you are running hadoop commands.

Do not forget to deploy client configuration. Select your cluster and click deploy client configuration option.

[image]

You can do this directly from cloudera manager web ui.

Or you can use cloudera manager REST API to refresh client configuration.

http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v16/path__clusters_-clusterName-_commands_deployClientConfig.html

"/api/v16/clusters/{clusterName}/commands/deployClientConfig"

POST http://admin.scmserver.com:7180/api/v16/clusters/mycluster/commands/deployClientConfig

Select the supported API Version.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesttion. I did't deploy client configuration because I did't understand it's meaning. Now I've done it through the web ui, and I can find some hadoop configuration files in /etc/hadoop/conf. But,it apperently did not set HADOOP_HOME enviroment, nor did it add hadoop bin path to system PATH. What should I do next?

Comment: Client configuration contains the necessary config parameters, environment variables and addresses of hadoop services such as name node, data nodes, resource managers, zookeeper servers, hive server and hive metastore, etc to access it from cli and other hadoop clients. You dont need to set HADOOP_HOME and other lib path. It is  set by default after deploying client configuration. It is available under /etc/hadoop/conf and /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs.

Comment: You can refer the same configs under /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/

Comment: I have the experience of installing and using hadoop stand alone, so I konw these configuration files. The problem is that I can not run hadoop command on shell. Should I create user cloudera-scm manully first? I am logging on the shell with root, and I can not su cloudera-scm.

Comment: For single mode all hadoop services are configured to run as cloudera-scm user. Hope this user is created during installation. Could you please share the screenshot.

Comment: I checked the passwd, and the cloudera-scm has no-login: 
cloudera-scm:x:497:495:Cloudera Manager:/var/lib/cloudera-scm-server:/sbin/nologin
Which screenshop do you need?

Comment: change login shell for the user cloudera-scm. Command to be executed as root user: " chsh cloudera-scm  ". /bin/bash shell is preferred over no login shell for debugging. It is not our problem here. Screenshot of the output when you executed hadoop command.

Comment: Here is the output after running  " chsh cloudera-scm ".
[root@master /]# su cloudera-scm
bash-4.1$ hadoop version
bash: hadoop: command not found